# Add class when gallery slider reaches end or beginning no matter size of gallery content

Tags: javascript, gallery

I have this simple scrolling gallery but can't figure out how to make the Prev/Next controls fade out (via a new class) when the end or beginning is reached.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T2Xe9/336/)

```
$('.changeImage').click(function() {
  $('#gallery_target').toggle('fast');
});

$('#gallery_next_nav').click(function () {
  $( "#gallery_nav" ).animate({
    scrollLeft: '+=519px'
  });
});

$('#gallery_prev_nav').click(function () {
  $( "#gallery_nav" ).animate({
    scrollLeft: '-=519px'
  });
});
```

I've tried a few things that didn't work, and can't find documentation that isn't just using a new plugin.